# performing merge while storing all other data and preserving order of original

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
idx  city           pop
A1   New York City  600
A2   Los Angeles    500
B1   Chicago        300
B2   Miami          200
```

and another dataframe that looks like this

```
idx  city           pop
A1   (-1.05, 3.45)  6.5
A2   (-1.15, 3.55)  6.3
B1   (-1.25, 3.65)  5.7
B2   (-1.35, 3.75)  4.8
```

I would like to perform a merge operation to achieve the following:

```
idx  city_x         city_y         pop_x  pop_y
A1   New York City  (-1.05, 3.45)  600    6.5
A2   Los Angeles    (-1.15, 3.55)  500    6.3
B1   Chicago        (-1.25, 3.65)  300    5.7
B2   Miami          (-1.35, 3.75)  200    4.8
```

Note that it is important for me to preserve this data column structure... I would like for it to merge as it belongs in the x, y, x, y, x, y format

The merge I am currently performing (to other data - not this dummy data):

`result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='idx', right_on='idx', how='left', suffixes=('_x', '_y'))`

but this is resulting in a dataframe that has `_x` on one side, and `y_` on another making it difficult for me to test against + make sure accuracy.

Am I performing merge properly?

Comment: If the ordering of the prefixes isn't important, you can probably get away with:`.sort_index(axis=1)`, perhaps set `idx` as the index beforehand if you want it to be the leftmost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only needs some simple sorting logic:

```
v = df1.merge(df2, on='idx')
result = v[sorted(v.columns, key=lambda x: df1.columns.get_loc(x.split('_')[0]))]
result

  idx         city_x         city_y  pop_x  pop_y
0  A1  New York City  (-1.05, 3.45)    600    6.5
1  A2    Los Angeles  (-1.15, 3.55)    500    6.3
2  B1        Chicago  (-1.25, 3.65)    300    5.7
3  B2          Miami  (-1.35, 3.75)    200    4.8
```

This reorders the result columns based on the position of the column name less suffix in the original DataFrames.

---

If the column names are different, use

```
def sorter(x):
    df = df1 if x in df1.columns else df2
    return df.columns.get_loc(x.split('_')[0])

v = df1.merge(df2, ...)
result = v[sorted(v.columns, key=sorter)
```

Comment: Hi @coldspeed, any chance you can help me with edits above?

Comment: @sgerbhctim Please include the full error message. I would also like to know the list of columns of both dataframes. Additionally, please follow suit as my answer shows and use `left.merge(right, ...)` and not `pd.merge(left, right, ...)` because there's a difference.

Comment: Edits above.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @sgerbhctim Thanks, have edited. Please let me know if you're having any more trouble.